# PHP array_merge not doing exactly what i need it to do

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

Ok so here is my first array:

```
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [27] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 27
                [type] => hardware
                [step_number] => 1

            )

        [372] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 372
                [type] => hardware
                [step_number] => 1

            )

        [92] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 92
                [type] => hardware
                [step_number] => 1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [335] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 335
                [type] => hardware
                [step_number] => 2

            )

        [62] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 62
                [type] => hardware
                [step_number] => 2
            )

        [356] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 356
                [type] => hardware
                [step_number] => 2
            )

    )
```

and here is my second array

```
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [655] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 655
                [type] => optional
                [step_number] => 1
            )

        [54] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 54
                [type] => optional
                [step_number] => 1
            )

        [554] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 554
                [type] => optional
                [step_number] => 1
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [33] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 33
                [type] => optional
                [step_number] => 2
            )
        [612] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 612
                [type] => optional
                [step_number] => 2
            )
        [5] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 5
                [type] => optional
                [step_number] => 2
            )
    ) 

 [3] => Array
            (
                [444] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 444
                        [type] => optional
                        [step_number] => 3
                    )
                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 6
                        [type] => optional
                        [step_number] => 3
                    )
                [53] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 53
                        [type] => optional
                        [step_number] => 3
                    )
            )
```

Basically what i need is the second array appended to the end of the first array with the keys of the first array preserved the keys and changing the step_number to the new key so the final keys looks like

```
(
[1] => Array
(
        [27] => Array
            (
                [step_number] => 1)
....
[2] => Array
(
        [335] => Array
            (
                [step_number] => 2)
....
[3] => Array
(
        [655] => Array
            (
                [step_number] => 3)
....
[4] => Array
(
        [33] => Array
            (
                [step_number] => 4)
....
[5] => Array
(
        [444] => Array
            (
                [step_number] => 5)
....
```

but when i do

```
$all = array_merge($first, $second);
```

the keys are

```
(
[0] => Array
[1] => Array
[2] => Array
[3] => Array
[4] => Array
```

Is that possible to do....

Comment: you lost me after the word "preserved".

Comment: basically i need to append the $second array to the end of the $first array but keeping the array_keys from the $first array and adding to it

Answer (score 2):

Try array_merge_recursive .. http://php.net/array_merge_recursive

Comment: this doesnt work because the elements start at 0 still like array_merge

Answer (score 0):

This is also from the manual on array_splice if you're just looking to append your 2nd array onto the first (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
 array_splice($first, count($first), 0, $second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the first set of keys, then using the [`Union array operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) should do the trick.

```
//$first = array(...);
//$second = array(...);

foreach ($second as $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($first[$key]))
    {
        $first[$key] = array();
    }

    $first[$key] += $value;
}
```